# Inequalities involving square roots.

Tags: inequality

I was trying to solve the following inequation:
$$
x^2≤16
\Rightarrow x≤\sqrt{16}
\Rightarrow x≤4 \text{ and } x≤-4
$$
But the solution given in my textbook is [-4,4], which is only possible when $x≥-4$ and $x≤4$. What have I done wrong?

(Sorry I could not format my question properly, I am new to this site.)

Comment: If $x \leq -4$ then $x^2 \geq 16$

Comment: You have to be very careful with the inequality signs! I think you just put one $\leq$ wrong, you should have put $\geq$.

Comment: Also: [Inequalities and Square Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2876265/42969).

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^2\leq 16 \Rightarrow |x|\leq \sqrt{16} \Rightarrow -4\leq x\leq 4
$$
The plot may help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write $$x^2\le 16$$ as $$(x-4)(x+4)\le 0$$

Comment: I tried solving it that way just now, I am getting x≤-4 and x≤4. I think I have done something wrong.

Comment: No it is $$-4\le x\le 4$$ the solution set.

Comment: So x≥-4, and I can't understand how is it so.

Comment: A product of two factors  is negative, if one factor is negative and the other one positive.

Comment: Taking the square root on both sides we get $$|x| \le 4$$

Comment: So $$x\le 4$$ or $$-x\le 4$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inequality
$$
f(x) = x^2 - 16 \leq 0
$$

A fool-proof way of always getting the inequality equations correct is the following:
Start with the equality (instead of inequality) equation. In this case, it's
$$
x^2 - 16 =0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x \in \left\{ -4, 4 \right\}
$$
The second step is to divide the real number line at these points. We have two points of division (two solutions), so we have to divide the number line into three parts. Now consider each of the part's sign individually.

1. First part is $x<-4$. What is the value of the expression ($f(x)$) in this area? We can plug in for example $x=-5$ and see that the answer is $f(-5) = 9>0$. Therefore, the expression is **positive** in this part of the number line.
2. Second part is $-4 \leq x \leq 4$. We can plug in for example $f(0) = -16<0$. The expression is **negative** in this part.
3. Third part is $x>4$. We can again plug in some test value, let's say $f(5) = 9>0$. In this part, the function is **positive**

Looking at the three sections, we see that the only part where $f(x)$ was negative was the second part. Therefore the answer is
$$
-4 \leq x \leq 4
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=-5$, which verifies $x\le-4$, doesn't it ?

But $x^2=25>16$ !

---

What you did wrong is to consider that

$$a^2\le b^2\implies a\le b$$ whatever $a,b$. This is not true when $b$ is negative !

---

**A trick:**

An inequation such as $f(x)\le0$ where $f$ is a continuous function is true in intervals that are delimited by the roots ($f(x)=0$), because by continuity you cannot change the sign without crossing zero.

The roots of your equation $x^2-16=0$ are $x=-4$ and $x=4$. They partition the real line in three intervals (ignoring the roots themselves),

$$(-\infty,-4),(-4,4),(4,\infty).$$

The solution set is made of the union of some of these intervals. You can pick *a single value* in each and check if they fulfill the inequation. E.g.

$$f(-5)=9>0,\\f(0)=-16<0,\\f(5)=9>0.$$

Now you should know where the solutions reside.

Answer (score 0):

It may be less confusing to use $|x|$, which is non-negative:

$$
|x|^2=x^2≤16
\implies |x|≤\sqrt{16}=4
\implies -4\le x≤4 
$$